# manifold tangent space show existence of one Dimensional manifold

Tags: calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I would appreciate help with this question :
Let $M \subset R^N$ be a smooth n-dimensional manifold ($n < N$)
$x_0 \in M$  and $h \in T_{x_0}M$
show existence of one Dimensional manifold $M_1$ such that $M_1 \subset M ,  x_0 \in M_1 , h \in T_{x_0}M_1$.